# C++ (function) template that return its unique argument without copying it for certain types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen, copy-elision

I have a function value(x) which is overloaded for many types such that:

```
double value(double x) { return x; }
double value(MyType x) { return x.value(); }
SomeContainer<double> value(SomeContainer<double> x) { return x; }
SomeContainer<double> value(SomeContainer<MyType> x) { ... }
```

where MyType is actually a number with a gradient vector with respect to a set of parameters.

for use in generic (template) programs.

I want to define:

```
Matrix<double> value(Matrix<double>)
Matrix<double> value(Matrix<MyType>)
```

I am using Eigen matrices and this is my current implementation of the first function:

```
template < typename Derived,
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point< typename Derived::Scalar >::value, int >::type = 0 >
Derived value( const Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived >& matrix )
{
    return matrix;
}
```

The problem is that this seems inefficient unless in possible cases where the compiler can figure out that the result/argument are not being modified and elude the copy. I also cannot return a reference to the argument since it is a local/temporary.

Basically what I would like is for value(x) to be compiled as the argument expression itself if the argument is a Matrix of double/float. I don't see how I can achieve this with a function template and a macro would not allow for specialization.

What could be done to avoid the copy?

### EDIT March 22, 2019:

If I replace the return type by

```
const Derived &
```

I get the following GCC warning:

```
warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

in the following code:

```
Matrix33 m;
m << 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     7, 8, 9;
std::cout << m << std::endl;
std::cout << value(m) << std::endl;
```

and the value(m) printout is garbage.

Also I am now thinking more and more this would be a bad idea to "return the object itself" because it is going to be used in generic code:

```
 auto m = value(Mx)
```

where Mx is a Matrix of X (template parameter) and m is a double matrix.

Having different semantics (stealing the object in case X is double and creating a separate object in other cases) could lead to many programming mistakes.

Another possibility would be to return proxy objects.

The best however would be for the compiler to see when a copy is not needed because nothing is being changed. However this does not seem to be the case: my benchmark to compare

```
  Matrix<double,3,3> M = ...
  norm(M)
```

and

```
  Matrix<double,3,3> M = ...
  norm(value(M))
```

shows that the second is a bit slower in a release (optimised) build.

Comment: How is `matrix` a local temporary in the code you provide? Perhaps add a snippet of how you call `value`. Can `SomeContainer` be something other than `Eigen::Matrix` (and is that part of this question)?

Comment: @chtz see my edit. Also I am using other Type<T> (not necessarily containers) for which I define value(Type<T>) returning Type<double>, but it is not a part of this question.

Comment: It is always a question you need to consider, if you want to have copies or references/views. I posted an answer which would create views in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `matrix.derived()` if you want to have a reference to the encapsulated type:

```
template < typename Derived,
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point< typename Derived::Scalar >::value, int >::type = 0 >
const Derived& value( const Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived >& matrix )
{
    return matrix.derived();
}
```

Regarding `value(Matrix<MyType> const&)`, you can implement that in a way that it returns just a view, essentially like this (requires C++14, or some more implementation work):

```
template < typename Derived,
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< typename Derived::Scalar, MyType >::value, int >::type = 0 >
auto value( const Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived >& matrix )
{
    // If `x.value()` returns by value, better use `unaryExpr` instead of `unaryViewExpr`:
    return matrix.unaryViewExpr([](const MyType& x){ return x.value();} );
}
```

Godbolt-Link: https://godbolt.org/z/qcYKnw
No warnings are generated and both `foo1` and `foo2` just tail-call the `norm` function. `foo3` has some small overhead, which likely would get optimized away if `norm` was inlined.

Comment: Thank you for this. I like the unaryExpr and I would use it for all cases (no need for std::enable_if). In the benchmark I have with Matrix<double,3,3> comparing norm(value) and norm() there is no overhead. However I have to support C++11 standard my compiler gives a warning about auto keyword. I tried using decltype, but it does not support lambdas. Also Eigen documentation specifies return type as const CwiseUnaryOp<CustomUnaryOp, const Derived> but I don't think I can specify CustomUnaryOp.

Comment: You can replace the lambda expression by a free function outside the `value` function. I think then `->decltype(...)` should work.